# Remove title using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

How to remove 2 or 3 characters at the begining of the string followed by a dot and may or may not be followed by a space?

```
i = 'mr.john'
i.replace("mr.","")
```

The above returns the name '**john**' correctly but not in all cases. For e.g.

```
i = 'smr. john'
i.replace("mr.","")
's john'
```

Expected result was '**john**'

Comment: E.g. `i.replace("smr.","").replace("mr.","")`? There are a lot of other ways.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness This does not work when there is no space. for e.g. 'mr.john'

Comment: Yeah, use `re.sub(r'^[^.]+\.(?:\s+)?','',i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want two or three characters at the start of the string followed by a dot and then maybe a space. As a regular expression this looks like `^\w{2,3}\. ?`.

Now you can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace this part with an empty string.

`cleaned_name = re.sub(r'(^\w{2,3}\. ?)', r'', name)`

Comment: If I need one, two or three characters, then 1,3 and not 1,2,3

Answer (score 2):

If you needed a more generic approach (`i` possibly having more names), you may use this code. You can define your own prefixes to remove:

```
import re

prefixes = ['mr', 'smr']
regex = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(prefixes) + r')\.\s*'
i = 'hi mr.john, smr. john, etc. Previous etc should not be removed'
i = re.sub(regex,'',i)
print(i)
```

You can test it live [here](https://ideone.com/CRu1t7)

The created regex is this:

```
\b   # Word boundary (to match 'mr' but not 'zmr' unless specified)
(?:group|of|prefixes|that|we|want|to|remove) # example
\.   # Literal '.'
\s*  # 0 or more spaces
```

Comment: you're missing `r` from the 2nd raw string, just sayin' ;)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks. You mean here: `')\.\s*'`? It seems to work with just the starting `r`

Comment: [*A backslash-character pair that is not a valid escape sequence now generates a DeprecationWarning. Although this will eventually become a SyntaxError, that will not be for several Python releases. (Contributed by Emanuel Barry in bpo-27364.)*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#deprecated-python-behavior) - `<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \. ')\\.\\s*'`; Python 3.6, 3.7 when written in file or if interpreter started with `-Wall`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, OK, so I wass missing the `-Wall`. Thanks, fixed

Comment: (and since 3.7, these warnings are displayed all the time when written in scripts)

Comment: But, you mean version 3.7 and using `-Wall` option, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.find` with slicing.

**Ex:**

```
i = 'smr. john'
print(i[i.find(".")+1:].strip())

i2 = 'mr.john'
print(i2[i2.find(".")+1:].strip())
```

**Output:**

```
john
john
```